# Orthoginal matrix from one vector

Tags: linear-algebra

We are asked to create an orthogonal matrix whose first column is (1/3;2/3;2/3).
I tried to express as (x; y; z) and (u;v;w) the two other columns and trying to solve a linear system but it ends to be so difficult.

Then I thought Gram-Schmidt Method but I have only one vector.

I would appreciate for your guidance.

Comment: Arbitrarily extend the given vector to a basis, e.g. using any two elements of the standard basis.

Comment: Two possible methods: 1) Pick a second orthogonal vector like $(2,-1,0)$, normalize and compute a third using the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) and another normalization. 2) Pick any two other vectors so that all three are linearly independent, for example $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ and perform Gram–Schmidt on all three.

Comment: Thank you very much, be well!